# QUICKBOOK v2 QBO Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Keep return me error when i try to access from a live quickbook account.
works well on my testing quickbook account(trial version).

here is the error.

```
Request URI
https://ca.qbo.intuit.com/qbo35/resource/accounts/v2/682735585
Request Headers
{
    "Authorization": "OAuth oauth_token=\"****\",oauth_nonce=\"*\",oauth_consumer_key=\"*\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1371061298\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"*%\"",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
Response Code
500
Response Headers
{
    "Content-Length": "38"
}
Response BodySelect body
Unable to connect to the remote server
```

Comment: Vincent, how did you generate that request URI for Canada?

Comment: Can you try to connect and test that live QB account using apiexplorer tool. 
Link - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer

Answer (score 0):

QBO V2 API doesn't support global companies( in this case CA).

Thanks